# How can I parse getItemAtPosition()?

Tags: java, android

I built a on item click event and I inserted this line to read a specific value from the item:

```
String test = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

And this line returns me this:

```
 {id=2, desc=test}
```

How can I parse this line to get only the ID from the item?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for us to give you the help you need, you must provide us with more information. But assume that you have some object defined for your adapter then you would do something like this:

```
YourListData data = (YourListData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
long id = data.getListId();
```

In which you might have:

```
public class YourListData {

    private long id;
    private String desc;

    public YourListData(){
    }


    public void setDesc(String desc){ this.desc = desc; }
    public void setListId(long name){ this.id = id; }

    public String getDesc(){ return this.desc; }
    public long getListId(){ return this.id; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `toString()`. Then you won't have to parse it. Instead you should call methods on the result of `getItemAtPosition()`.